# Don't оpen custom link from browser

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

My app can open a special link. It's great when I click to link in a mail or saved note. But I do not want see a dialog with a choice of app when i click on a link from the browser. User has chosen browser and went to my site, and it turns out that at each transition to a new page it is necessary to choose the browser again. Can I somehow disable the selection of the app, if clicked on a link in the browser?

P.S. Sorry for my english.

Comment: The application does not support all pages of the site. If the user is already on my site open in his favorite browser, I do not want to offer it to run the application. But if he wants to open a link, which is shared with him while he is not on my site, I want to give him the opportunity to choose how to open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in manifest:

```
        <activity

             ...

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            ...

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

i removed the line:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
```

and it works as I wanted.

Thank all for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inbuilt Webview instead. This won't open a new browser. http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: The application does not support all pages of the site. If the user is already on my site open in his favorite browser, I do not want to offer it to run the application. But if he wants to open a link, which is shared with him while he is not on my site, I want to give him the opportunity to choose how to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.google.android.browser","com.google.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
intent.setComponent(comp);
intent.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.BROWSABLE");
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
intent.setData(uri);
try
{
    startActivity(intent);
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: This code open link in browser. It is not that i want. Read my comment to post. There may be more understandable described.